# How can i search Mamtakumari by passing regex on to_tsquery(ku) in full text search implimention of postgressql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I want to use full text search functionality over postgres where when I'm using to_tsquery('ku:*') then it's showing result like Kumar, Kusum etc. but not like Mamtakumari and my requirement is to get like Mamtakumari without using like operator. Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to do the job but without using the right tool to do the job?

Comment: Right, this is not about full text search, but about pattern matching. You could use a trigram index, but that won't work for a search string with only two characters, and you will end up with a sequential scan. You cannot do better for a search string like that.

Comment: It is required for my application where we have to implement search in it and their are four columns we have name, pincode,mobile,I'd so we want to implement single query for API so user can get the name as per suggestion we r getting in like operator. This is my requirement and I'm using postgresdb for this and it's full text search functionality.